# outgoing call information through android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, phone-call, outgoing-call

I want to find some events after I dialed for a number, i.e at the destination side, the call is accepted or rejected or busy or not-reachable. How to find these events in android. I got found some API's in android.TelephonyManager but those for IN_COMMING_CALL. And I am using BroadcastReceiver() to find events after i dialed for number. the piece of code is,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("before if condition");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            System.out.println("**outgoingcall***");
        }       
};
```

I am unable to find the call is accepted or rejected or busy at destination device. are there any network based API's to find these events during outgoing_call in android? please help me

also I used PhoneStateListener, the code is

```
private class ListenToPhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        Log.i("telephony-example", "State changed: " + stateName(state));
    }

    String stateName(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: 
            System.out.println("phone is idle****");
            break;  
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: 
            System.out.println("phone is offhook****");
            break;  
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            System.out.println("phone is Ringing***");
            break;  
        }
        return Integer.toString(state);
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the events on Outgoing_call..
Thanks
shiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) or watch for [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) broadcast Intents.

Comment: Thanks a lot hovanessyan. my code is working fine with the ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED API.

Comment: @Shiv, My problem is just like your problem, how you solve, in which action you register your receiver in manifast